# Add Cache in a class

Tags: spring

I have a impl class where I have 2 update methods , method1 is updating complete row in DB whereas method2 is updating only one column in DB of that table.

Now I need to use @Caceable and @CacheEvict here , How can I use in this condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring 3.1 introduces a new feature to allow methods to be cached and evicted thus allowing resource heavy methods to be avoided where possible. Caching is enabled via the new `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` annotations.

One example of caching would be, for example, database activity. We can apply the `@Cacheable` annotation to a find operation and then apply the `@CacheEvict` to an update / delete operation.  In this sense, caching would work much like a second level cache in Hibernate or JPA.

To enable caching on a find method, the method needs to be annotated with the `@Cacheable` annotation identifying which cache to use.  Spring allows multiple caches to be defined each of which can be backed by a different caching abstraction.

```
@Cacheable("items") //@Cacheable(value = "items", key = "#itemId")
public Item find(long itemId) {
    Item item = entityManager.find(Item.class, itemId);
    return item;
}
```

When it is time to invoke the find method, Spring checks in the specified cache to see if the results of the operation have already been cached and if the results can be therefore be returned from cache instead of invoking the method. Spring uses the method arguments as the key, so in this case the itemId parameter.

To evict an entry from the cache when an object is updated in the database, the `@CacheEvict` annotation can be used.  Again, this annotation takes a parameter identifying which cache to use.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "items", key = "#item.id")
public void updateItem(Item item) {
    entityManager.merge(item);
}
```

**EDIT:**

**@CacheEvict**
Used for Cache-removal /cache-cleanup operation. `@CacheEvict` annotation indicates that a method (or all methods on a class) triggers a cache evict operation, removing specific [or all] items from cache. Various attributes provides complete control to enforce the required behavior for cache-eviction.

for example,

```
@CacheEvict(value = "products", key = "#product.name")
public void refreshProduct(Product product) {
    //This method will remove only this specific product from 'products' cache.
} 

@CacheEvict(value = "products", allEntries = true)
public void refreshAllProducts() {
    //This method will remove all 'products' from cache, say as a result of flush-all API.
}
```

Comment: Above is for when we have one  get method [ where we can use @Cacheable] and one set/update method where we can use @CacheEvict.

in my class I have 2 update method [ 1 is updating compete record of the row and 2nd is updating only one column of the row in DB] . So in this condition how can I use CacheEvict ?

Comment: @BhupendraSingh If you need to update the records, go for CacheEvict. Updated the answer for using CacheEvict for one record and all records.